# Converting a mixed model with repeated and random effects and different covariance structures from SAS to R

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have a model, created in SAS by a colleague, with a repeated effect that has an ARH1 (autoregressive heterogeneous variances) covariance structure and a random effect (with a variance components covariance structure) that I am trying to re-create in R, where I have more experience.

The original SAS code is:

```
PROC MIXED DATA=mylib.sep_cover_data plots=all ALPHA=0.15 CL COVTEST;
CLASS soil_grp dummy_year plot pasture;
MODEL  cover = pcp soil_grp / ALPHA=0.15 CL residual SOLUTION;
RANDOM pasture / ALPHA=0.15 CL SOLUTION;
REPEATED dummy_year / subject = plot type = ARH(1);
```

After looking through other similar questions on here, I'm pretty sure I'm able to re-create the repeated statement in R, including the covariance structure, using the nlme library:

```
library(nlme)
cover.data <- read.csv("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=donload&id=0Bxdatltmq5ljMVlObXh1NHFGck0", header = TRUE)
cover.data <- cover.data[cover.data$Flag=="data",]
cover.data$soil_grp <- factor(cover.data$soil_grp)
cover.data$dummy_year <- factor(cover.data$dummy_year)
cover.data$pcp <- as.numeric(as.character(cover.data$pcp))
cover.data$cover <- as.numeric(as.character(cover.data$cover)) 

model.test1 <- gls(cover ~ Pcp + soil_grp, corr = corAR1(, form = ~ 1 | year/plot), weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | dummy_year), data = cover.data, na.action = "na.omit")
```

but I can't figure out how to add in the random effect (with a different covariance structure) into this model.

Additionally, I can put both the repeated and random variables into the same model but don't know how to specify the covariance structures for them.

```
model.test2 <- lme(cover ~ Pcp_jan_jun + soil, random = list( plot = ~ 1, pasture = ~1), data = cover.data, na.action = "na.omit")
```

Is is possible to put both a repeated and random effect with different covariance structures into the same model in R? If so, how do I code R to do it?

The data can be downloaded from 
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=donload&id=0Bxdatltmq5ljMVlObXh1NHFGck0

Comment: I would expect better response to be had at either CrossValidate.co or the R-mixed-models mailing list.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. `lme` got the same `correlation` and `weights` parameters as `gls`.

Comment: My problem is not getting the lme and gls to match, it is that I can't figure out how to re-create the exact SAS model in R. The gls model (model.test1) in R re-creates the repeated statement from the SAS model with the correct covariance structure but I can't figure out how to add in the random statement. The lme model (model.test2) includes both the repeated and random from the SAS model but I can't figure out how to specify the covariance structures of each.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that x1, and x2 are time-dependent covariates for which we want to estimate a random effect, time is a discrete-time variable for which we consider both a random effect and correlated measurements, the model which specifies the correlation of both random effects and the repeated measurements should look something like this:

```
model <- lme(y ~ x1 + x2 + time, random = list(subjects = pdSymm(~ x1 + x2 + time)), correlation = corSymm(form = ~ 1 | subjects), weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | time), data = your_data, method = "REML")
```

This should generate a random effects model with correlated intercept, x1, x2 and time random effects components. Also, we will get correlated repeated measurements. All random components and repeated time measurements have their variance estimated here because "pdSymm" and "corSymm" are chosen. This means that the variance-covariance structures are actually "unstructured correlation metric", as they are named in other statistical analysis software packages. This is a very general structure. It can be used as such, or as a starting point and be compared later with other simpler structures.